# SQL query about timeline likes

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm writing something similar to facebook timeline that user can see all the post and also see a blue thumb if the user has liked that post before.

Here are the two tables,

```
Posts
PostID  | USERID   | MORE COLS....
1       | 1        | ....
2       | 1        | ....
3       | 3        | ....
4       | 5        | ....

Likes
LikeID  | POSTID | USERID   | MORE COLS....
1       | 1      | 1        | ....
2       | 1      | 5        | ....
3       | 2      | 1        | ....
4       | 3      | 6        | ....
```

My question is that how can I write a sql query to get all the posts and also know if the user has liked these posts before?

So for example the ideal result of the query would be like
(if this user's id is 1)

```
All Posts
PostID  | LikedByMeBefore   | ....
1       | true              | ....
2       | false             | ....
3       | true              | ....
4       | true              | ....
5       | false             | ....
6       | false             | ....
.       | .                 | ....
.       | .                 | ....
```

Comment: I have tried to left join Likes with Posts, however there will be duplicates if one post has been liked many times and also I don't think it's efficient too.

Comment: a user shouldn't be able to like a post more than once though?

Comment: yes, but it could be liked by other usesr. If I do SELECT P.id FROM POST P   LEFT JOIN Likes L ON P.id = L.postid, then it will have duplicates. What I need is to get all the posts and to know if I have liked each individual post or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unclear what the `UserID` column is in the `Posts` table, but I can assume it's the user who created it. The `UserID` in the Likes table is more obvious though. You need to use a `LEFT JOIN` combined with `ISNULL`:

```
DECLARE @UserID INT = 5

SELECT Posts.PostID, ISNULL(Likes.LikeID, 0) AS LikedByMeBefore, ...more columns...
FROM Posts
LEFT JOIN Likes
    ON Posts.PostID = Likes.PostID
    AND (Likes.UserID = @UserID OR Likes.UserID IS NULL)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, David, I tried this before, the problem is that it doesn't get all the posts, if a post is liked by another user then it won't show up. Do you have any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, however say if post number 5 is liked only by UserID 2, then it I could not get it using the above query.

Comment: Cool that works! I've never seen this syntax before, thanks for answering. I suppose the performance of this query should be better than using exists as MegaTron suggested?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, you want to get information about "likes" for all the posts for the current user? Right?
So, Please try this for current user:

```
declare @CurrentUserID int
SET @CurrentUserID = 1
    select P.PostID  
    ,       case 
             when exists (select 1 from Likes L where L.POSTID = P.PostID   and L.USERID   = @CurrentUserID) 
             then 'yes' else 'no' 
            end LikedBefore   
    from Posts P
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I tried it and it worked! Sorry I'm not familiar with SQL, if the table grows bigger, will it take long to run?